# How can I access a Dictionary through a key hashcode?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like that:

```
 Dictionary<MyCompositeKey, int>
```

Clearly `MyCompositeKey` is a class I designed which implements `IEqualityComparer` and thus has a `GetHashCode` method.

As far as I know, dictionary uses the key's hash to access the value, so here's my question:

While I can easily access the value via `dict.TryGetValue(new MyCompositeKey(params))`, I wanted to get rid off the `new` overhead on each access.

For this reason I was wondering if there's a way to access the value directly from key's hash (which I can compute with a very lower overhead).

Comment: The `TKey` (in your case `MyCompositeKey`) shall not implement `IEqualityComparer`; that is wrong. Either `MyCompositeKey` shall override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`, or else you shall pass ___another___ object which implements `IEqualityComparer<>` to the `Dictionary<,>` constructor.

Comment: I can remove the implementation and keep the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides. This won't change my question.

Comment: Right, this is just a comment, not an answer to the question. But do not confuse the `GetHashCode()` method inherited (from `object`) by all classes and structs with the `GetHashCode(T)` method present in `IEqualityComparer<in T>`.

Comment: Okay thank you, figured out the difference after a little googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that.

Note that hash collisions may occur, so there could be many keys in the `Dictionary<,>` matching the given hash. We need `Equals` to find out which (if any) is correct.

You talk about `new` overhead. Are you sure it is significant in your case?

If it is, you could consider making `MyCompositeKey` an **immutable** `struct` instead of a `class`. It might be faster in some cases, eliminating the need for the garbage collector to remove all those "loose" keys from memory.

If `MyCompositeKey` is a `struct`, the expression `new MyCompositeKey(params)` only loads all the `params` onto the call stack (or CPU registers or whatever the run-time figures is best).

---

Addition: If you go for a `struct`, consider implementing `IEquatable<>`. It will look like this:

```
struct MyCompositeKey : IEquatable<MyCompositeKey>
{
  // readonly fields/properties

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (obj is MyCompositeKey)
      return Equals((MyCompositeKey)obj); // unbox and go to below overload

    return false;
  }

  public bool Equals(MyCompositeKey other) // implements interface, can avoid boxing
  {
    // equality logic here
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    // hash logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that struct allocation is somehow faster (although requires more RAM). As I have time costraints but no RAM costraints (I have 16GB in destination computer), I guess using a struct may be the winning idea.

Comment: @Fylax Structs should always be faster than classes, assuming that you're actually using them for their intended purpose.

Comment: @Krythic it basically is a `KeyValuePair` (which is a struct) with custom `Equals` and `GetHashCode` , so it should make sense

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses an internal buckets collection which you cannot access from outside the class - it is `private`.

As you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1), the access method first determines the bucket (according to the hash code) and then accesses the item by index:

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) 
{
    int i = FindEntry(key);
    if (i >= 0) 
    {
        value = entries[i].value;
        return true;
    }

    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}

private int FindEntry(TKey key) 
{
    if (buckets != null) 
    {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) 
        {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) 
                return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```